# How do I find the averge value of the function g(x) on the interval [1, + infinity]?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I know how to find the average value of functions on an interval, but I am having trouble finding the average value of this function with the interval going to positive infinity. I tried doing what the hint says, but I'm not sure if I am on the right track. Can anyone suggest anything? Thank You!

[image]

Comment: You want $b-1$ in the denominator, not $1-b$.

Comment: oops sorry about that

Comment: Now do a change of variable $u=\frac{\pi}{x}$, evaluate the integral and take the limit.

Comment: oh, so you mean I should do a u-substitution

Answer (score -1):

Given the amount of your homework you have posted in the past four hours...

Hint: $u = \frac{\pi}{x}$.

Comment: So I solved by first substituting u for pi/x. ThenI evaluated the integral and when I took the limit I got the answer 0. Is this correct?

Comment: @P1081 : What do you think?  Have you checked for the sorts of errors you have seen before?  Can you convince yourself, perhaps by graphing $g(x)$ that the answer could plausibly be near $0$?